# Program ignores `if ( argc != 2)` statement

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing a problem set from the CS50 course, and in this problem `argc` needs to be 2. I made this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, string argv [])
{
    if ( argc != 2){
        printf ("Retry\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        int x = atoi(argv [1]);
        string a = get_string ("Enter plaintext: ");
        printf ("%s", a);
        printf ("%d", x);
        }
}
```

But even when `argc` is different than 2 it ignores the if statement and goes to the else statement.

Why is that? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you prove your statement? Like by printing the `argc`?

Comment: By the way, shouldn't string argv [] be char* argv []? Where is string defined as char *?

Comment: You are aware that a call like `cs50.exe p1 p2` yields an `argc==3`, are you?

Comment: @Makketronix See https://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h

Comment: You are making something up.

Comment: @AnT Who's making up what?

Comment: How are you passing the arguments?

Comment: Please show the sample input (i.e. the commandline including parameters which is used to execute the program). Also please insert the print proposed by Eugene and show the output.

Comment: Upvoted due to the quality of the question. It would be a good time to run this through your debugger. Debugging is more important than typing out code.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like that. Perhaps it should be cstring instead.

Comment: @Makketronix `string` is a typedef of `char*` in the cs50 header.

Comment: @George: Indeed it is and it's very naughty since string literals decay to a `const char*` type.

Comment: Turns out I forgot that the command itself counted as 1. Silly mistake.

Comment: @Adam Grey Even if `<cs50.h>` has a `typedef char *string;`, In C, the standard library defines "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character.". An _array_ can be a _string_. A _string_ is **not** a pointer.  A pointer is not a string.  `char *` is a pointer and not a _string_, although a `char *` can point to a _string_.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yup it's pretty bad, i'd hope that a modern C compiler would warn about the conversion and make it obvious to a tutor that `string` shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Makketronix Imo it just shouldn't exist at all :p I really don't see the rationale behind it, and its use is often abused i.e. I was taught once upon a time that `string some_string; scanf("%s", some_string);` is clean and correct (though admittadley, we were using a different library. `string` was still just a `typedef` of `char*`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure that you're forgetting that the command itself counts as one of the args from the shell.  In other words:

```
> myprog myparam myotherparam
```

has argc == 3 because myprog is arg[0]